# trying to get the method working, converting roman numerals to integer.

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get this method working and it gives me the error :16:in `block (2 levels) in roman_to_integer': undefined method`indlude?'
I can't see why. Please help. 
Im just learning but i cant see why the it doesnt think roman is a string.

```
def roman_to_integer roman
      result = 0
     singles = {"M"=> 1000, "D"=> 500, "C"=> 100,"L"=> 50, "X"=> 10, "V"=> 5, "I"=> 1}   

    double = {"CM"=> 900,"CD"=> 400,"XC"=> 90,"XL"=> 40,"XL"=> 40,"IX"=> 9, "IV"=> 4,}

    roman= roman.upcase
    something = roman.split("")
    something.each do |key|
    unless singles.include?(key)

      puts "not valid roman numeral"
    end

    double.each do |key, value|
        if roman.indlude?(key)
            result += value
            roman.slice!(key)
         end
     end
     while roman.length > 0
        single.each do |key, value|
            if single.include?(key)
                result += value
                roman.slice!(key)
            end 
        end
    end


    end
    result
  end
```

Comment: include? not indlude? :|

Comment: `indlude?` is not a method, indeed. Enable spellchecker in your editor.

Answer (score 1):

You mean `include`, not `indlude`. Remember, this is a machine, and the concept of typos is an extremely tricky one to explain to it.